# Akka default dispatcher having many waiting threads

Tags: akka, threadpool, akka-cluster

Akka application spins a lot of new dispatchers overtime instead of reusing .
The old dispatchers are going back to waiting state and never been reused or terminated.

We use akka's default dipatcher with fork-join executors. we do override the default parellism parameter between our actors based on actors purpose.

Is there a configuration that we are missing that causing this issue?

Comment: We were able to solve this issue by chaging my executors for those blocking actors. As a general pattern its  better to use thread pool executors instead of fork join pool executors for blocking actors. Below link has the actual discussion with Akka groups folks. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/9M5p7yllZ-w . Thanks Kanard malawski .

Comment: We are faing a similar situation where we have too many threads inw aiting state. Refered the google link , did you follow the same and found any correct soultion.